# Notarizing App Distributed Out of App Store

Tags: macos, applications, catalina, notarization

I don't have an Apple Developer ID and I have an installer and app, neither signed nor notarized. Apple now blocks the App in Catalina and even the `Open` option won't work. Rather than  I seek information   to authenticate these.

What is the process to register and notarize for macOS?

**Update:**
I'm asking from the developer's perspective .. not as a user.

Comment: Do you want to distribute the installer and application to the general public or within a controlled environment like a school or organisation?

Comment: @GrahamMiln General Public.I currently do not use AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

## Limited Options

As a developer wanting to distribute unsigned and unnotarized applications, your options are increasingly limited on macOS. You would [not be alone](https://mjtsai.com/blog/tag/notarization/) disliking this trend.

If your users are technical, the [advice from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491) can be referenced in your documentation. This will help a few potential users but will dramatically limit your audience.

### Apple's Advice to Users

Apple provide [Safely open apps on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491) for users wishing to open unsigned and unnotarized applications on the latest versions of macOS.

### Alternative Certificate Authority

In theory, you could code sign your application using another certificate authority that has an appropriate root certificate pre-installed in macOS. This assumes you wish to avoid dealing with Apple, rather than wishing to avoid code signing.

#### Is an Apple Developer Account Mandatory?

I suspect an Apple Developer Account is not mandatory, but not having an account will make some tasks difficult.

Given you have a code signing certificate from Comodo (Sectigo), you could try using [`codesign`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/codesign/) with it.

The [manual for `codesign`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/codesign/) does not obviously state a requirement for an Apple issued certificate. A code signing certificate with a trusted root certificate in macOS should be useable.

You will need to create a new Keychain containing the certificate and private key. Then pass the absolute path of the keychain file to `codesign` via `--keychain`.

One possible problem you may run into is macOS's [`spctl`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/8/spctl/), aka [Gatekeeper](https://mjtsai.com/blog/tag/gatekeeper/). `spctl`'s rules may state the signing certificate must have a root Apple certificate. Investigate the `spctl` tool on macOS.

I recommending trying `codesign` with your certificate and then [ask more questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as specific problems arise.

Comment: Thanks.I already have a code signing certificate from Comodo(Sectigo) which is used to sign my windows app.Can this be used in OSX as well ? Is signing up for Apple Dev program mandatory?

Comment: I have expanded the answer. Good luck! As an aside, [Indie](https://indie.miln.eu) might be useful to you.

Comment: I have tried signing my existing application using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204407/how-to-codesign-an-existing-mac-os-x-app-file-for-gatekeeper but i keep getting this exception https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1940/_index.html . Can you please advice

Comment: @techno please can you [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), as this will attract answers. Comments tend to be less visible. For example, I did not get a notification from your follow up comment.